# Long mode (64 bit) relative call with a 64 bit immediate value

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, intel

Is it possible? Intel documentation says opcode E8 can be used with a relative displacement value.

E8 cd   CALL rel32

"Call near, relative, 
displacement relative to next instruction. 32-bit displacement sign extended to 64-bits in 64-bit mode."

Does it mean only 32 bit displacements are allowed? I am quite unclear on the wording here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It means that the opcode is followed by a 32-bit displacement. If you want longer, you can compute it yourself with an `lea` and an indirect call.